# Cracks and holes in tile floor grout. How urgent is this to fix?

Tags: tile, waterproofing, grout, water-damage

This is related to [What to do about holes in tile grout?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58379/what-to-do-about-holes-in-tile-grout), but it involves a whole-house tile floor rather than a shower, and my question is not about how to repair it, but how urgent the repair is. The floor has a few cracks and pinholes in the grout (photos below). It's not hard to find instructions for repairing this, but what's unclear to me is whether there is likelihood of water damage if the floor is mopped while the holes remain.

[image: Missing grout]
[image: Cracked grout]
[image: Cracked grout]
[image: Pinholes and divots]

Comment: Only if excessive mopping or spilling the bucket over.  Regular mopping usually just making the floor quite damp.  Dirt and other nasty things might build up in the larger places.  Wet rooms(bathrooms) should be done sooner than later.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks. Fortunately, I haven't seen any large cracks in the bathrooms (so far), just smaller pinholes.